# ¿Como lleno una multilista?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2017

Tengo una lista enlazada con otra lista de esta forma:

```
struct lista {  
    int valor;  
    lista *prox;  
}  

struct multi {  
    int valor;  
    multi *prox;  
    lista *abajo;  
};  

void insertarcabmulti(multi **cab, int x) {  
    multi *t = new multi;  
    t->valor = x;  
    t->prox = *cab;  
    *cab = t;  
}  

int main() {  
    int op = -1, x = 0, y = 0;  
    multi *p = NULL;  
    while (op) {  
        system("cls");  
        printf("\n\n\t\tMENU DE MANEJO DE MULTILISTAS \n ");  
        printf("1.\tInsertar por comienzo de lista\n ");  
switch (op) {  
        case 1: printf("\nIndique dato a insertar\n");  
            scanf_s("%i", &x);  
            insertarcabmulti(&p, x);  
            break;  
}  
        system("pause");  
    };   
}
```

Pero no tengo idea de cómo llenar ambas listas, haga lo que haga siempre logro llenar todo lo que corresponde a "multi" pero no tengo idea de como llenar "lista", ¿alguien me puede ayudar? Mi mayor problema es accediendo a la informacion de "lista", no tengo idea de como hacerlo, deberia ser (apuntador hacia `multi->abajo->valor`)? ¿O como?

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje? ¿En [tag:c] o en [tag:c++]? No hay ningún punto del código en que estés usando `multi->abajo->valor` ¿Cuál es exáctamente el problema?

Comment: En C, pero estoy usando el compilador de visual studio 2017, por eso no hay typedef ni nada parecido como usualmente se utiliza en c, lo de multi->abajo->valor era solo para plantear una pregunta, no es relacionada con el codigo.

El problema es que no se como llenar la lista "Lista" que esta enlazada con "Multi"

Comment: Si es C, tu programa no compila pues las estructuras deben anteponerse de la palabra clave `struct` para instanciarse, así que lo que comentas del `typedef` es opuesto a lo que muestras ¿no te estarás refiriendo a C++?

Answer (score 2):

Cuesta de entender tu problema sin describir lo que entiendes por "*multilista*". Por el código puedo deducir que es una lista de listas. De ser así, estás cometiendo el error más común de la etiqueta [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) de Stack Overflow en Español:

#### Los nodos no son listas.

He visto en StackOverflow en Español varias veces esta confusión, y me resulta muy curioso que tantos usuarios cometan ese error.

Usas una estructura que contiene un puntero al siguiente elemento y la llamas lista. Y eso es tan erróneo como decir que un escalón es una escalera, sinceramente ¿Te parecen lo mismo?:

[image]
[image]

#### Propuesta.

Yo te propongo crear un objeto lista, con sus métodos de inserción y borrado y cuyo tipo almacenado sea genérico, es decir: una plantilla (`template`); una vez tengas una lista plantilla puedes hacer una lista de listas:

```
template <typename TIPO>
struct lista
{
    void insertar(TIPO t)
    {
        if (fin)
        {
            fin->siguiente = new nodo{t};
            fin = fin->siguiente;
        }
        else
        {
            inicio = fin = new nodo{t};
        }
    }

private:
    struct nodo
    {
        TIPO valor;
        nodo *siguiente = nullptr;
    };

    nodo *inicio = nullptr;
    nodo *fin = inicio;
};
```

Esto la lista más sencilla que puedes hacer, el nodo es un tipo privado porque siguiendo los principios de [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)) el usuario no necesita conocer los nodos para utilizar la lista. Ten en cuenta que no he añadido el destructor (para liberar la memoria dinámica solicitada), eso ya sería cosa tuya. Esta lista podría usarse así:

```
lista<int> l;
l.insertar(1);
l.insertar(2);
l.insertar(3);
l.insertar(4);
```

En cuanto a la multilista, podrías declararla así:

```
template <typename TIPO>
using multilista = lista<lista<TIPO>;

multilista<int> ml; // Lista de listas de int.
```

Para que funcione adecuadamente deberías añadir un constructor de copia al objeto lista:

```
lista(const lista &l)
{
    for (auto i = l.inicio; i; i = i->siguiente)
        insertar(i->valor);
}
```

Usa esto como guía para crear una lista de listas, puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RdnmsR5tOorZCAIG)</kbd>.

Comment: Creo que empieza a tener sentido que elabores una pregunta / respuesta genérica para explicar la diferencia entre nodo y lista... así podremos enlazar a la misma (o marcar la pregunta como duplicada)...